# How to go into recovery mode? Intex Cloud Cube v08

Tags: rooting, recovery-mode, system

I rooted Intex Cloud Cube v08 and installed an xposed module. After restarting the device it says

> "unfortunately system UI has stopped"

and after tapping on ok it again shows the same. It is still the same after restarting.

I tried key combinations

**volume down + power key**
-: It is going into safe mode but not recovery mode

**volume up + power key**
-: Just restarting normally

I don't have custom recovery

How to solve this problem and go into the stock recovery mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved now. Thanks to a comment suggesting [this link](https://www.mobilereset99.com/intex-mobile-recovery-mode/) (Use volume buttons to move and power button to select any option)

> **Method 1**
>
> - Power off your Intex Mobile, by holding the power button.
> - Hold down the Volume Up + Power Button.
> - After that, Release both Buttons when you see Intex Logo or Android Logo appears.
> - Now you can see Android Recovery Mode.
>
> **Method 2**
>
> - Power off your Intex Mobile, by holding the power button.
> - Hold down the Volume Down + Power Button.
> - After that, Release both Buttons when you see Intex Logo or Android Logo appears.
> - Now you can see Android Recovery Mode.
>
> **Method 3**
>
> - Power off your Intex Mobile, by holding the power button.
> - Hold down the Volume Up + Home + Power Button.
> - After that, Release both Buttons when you see Android exclamation mark appears.
> - Now you can see Android Recovery Mode, if not (While holding down the Power button press and release Volume Up Button).
>
> **Method 4**
>
> - Power off your Intex Mobile, by holding the power button.
> - Hold down the Volume Up + Power Button.
> - After that, Release both Buttons when you see Android exclamation mark appears.
> - Next, While holding down the Power button press and release Volume Up Button.
> - Now you can see Android Recovery Mode.

I tried the 4th method in the link.
But since <kbd>volume up</kbd> + <kbd>power</kbd>  was restarting the device normally, I held down the <kbd>power</kbd>  and was pressing and releasing the <kbd>volume up</kbd> 
 button.
The device didn't go in recovery mode but it rebooted and started working **without** the popup "unfortunately system UI has stopped".

Comment: Thanks for posting +1. You can [accept](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) after 48 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your phone in particular and a quick search gave me nothing, but holding down Volume up + Power + Home also seems to be a common combination for recovery mode.

Worth a try I guess.

Comment: Thanks for replying appreciate it